# Is it mandatory to capitalize the enum variables in .proto files?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-python, grpc-go

I want to create a enum of the following format but my proto extension throws an error, is it mandatory to capitalise enums and use only underscores ?

```
enum Language {
    en = 0;
    en-uk =1;
    en-gb =2;
    en-au =3;
    en-us =4;
    fil-en =5;
    en-in =6;
    fr =7;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the proto3 language specification, [identifiers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto3-spec#identifiers) (including enums) **must** begin with a letter and then can contain **only** letters, decimal digits and underscores.

> `ident = letter { letter | decimalDigit | "_" }`

---

Here's what Google's developer style guide recommends for [enums](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/style#enums). While the style guide is technically not mandatory, you should take care to conform to naming conventions in most situations, unless you have a compelling reason to depart from them.

> Use CamelCase (with an initial capital) for enum type names and CAPITALS_WITH_UNDERSCORES for value names:
>
> ```protobuf
> enum FooBar {
>   FOO_BAR_UNSPECIFIED = 0;
>   FOO_BAR_FIRST_VALUE = 1;
>   FOO_BAR_SECOND_VALUE = 2;
> }
> ```